# Linux script to extract usernames from text file

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, extract

I am a beginner at scripting but I created a text file called text.dat which contains only usernames in the file location /home/daniel/text.dat and I’m trying to run a script(called addusers.sh) that displays the names from that text file and will create a new user account on the system for each new user account specified in the text.dat file. For each user account that is created, append a line entry to the /home/daniel/logs/useraccounts.log file.  The line entry will contain the following information:  `added | <user account name> | <day and time of creation>`.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo “cat text.dat”
newuser= grep /home/daniel/text.dat
sudo adduser $newuser
```

Comment: You have given everything about your requirement except what is the data structure in input file.

Comment: You may find this [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) thread helpful: [How should I add users non-interactively?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/how-should-i-add-users-non-interactively)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C
myuser="/home/george/text.dat"

# create logs directory
mkdir -p ~/logs

# create log file
touch ~/logs/useraccounts.log

# make sure admin is running the script
[ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"


# check if log file is empty, if not don't add a new header
file="~/logs/useraccounts.log"

# Add header in logs file if one isn't already there.
if [[ -s $file ]]
then
    # log file header

    printf "%s %12s %s %18s %s %32s %s\n" "|" "Added" "|" "User Account Name" "|" "Day and Time of Creation" "|" >> ~/logs/useraccounts.log

    printf "%50s\n" "========================================================================" >> ~/logs/useraccounts.log

fi


# remove any whitespaces and blank lines from file input
# before passing it to 'while command'
sed '/^[ \t]*$/d' $myuser | while read -r line
do
        name="$line"

        adduser --disabled-login --gecos "" $name


        # check if user was successfully added
        isthere=$(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep "$name")


        # if user was added then make insert record into log file
        if [[ "$isthere" == "$name" ]]
        then

                 printf "%s %10s   %s %17s  %s %33s %s\n"  "|" "Yes" "|" "$name"  "|" "$(date)" "|"  >> ~/logs/useraccounts.log 

        else

                 printf "%s %10s   %s %17s  %s %33s %s\n"  "|" "No" "|" "$name"  "|" "$(date)" "|"  >> ~/logs/useraccounts.log



        fi   




done
```

Several things to note here:

- Created users can't *log in* until a password has been set for each of them.
- The `printf` will have to be altered to suit your own style.